# Согласование или управление?

Tags: словосочетания

Давно хочу выяснить, какой тип подчинительной связи используется в словосочетании, состоящем из количественного числительного и существительного. Например, двадцать дней. С одной стороны, двадцать чего? дней, зависимое слово - существительное, и это управление. С другой стороны, при склонении одного слова изменяется и другое: двадцати дней, двадцатью днями, двадцати дням - это согласование.

Answer (score 4):

**Основное правило для грамматических (количественных и собирательных) числительных:**

1. Числительные в И.- В. падеже  **управляют**  Р.П. существительных в форме 
   ед. или мн. числа: два стола, пять книг, двое юношей. ГЛАВНЫМ СЛОВОМ в сочетании является ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ.
2. В остальных (косвенных) падежах  числительные **согласуются** в падеже с  существительными мн. числа: нет двух столов, по двум столам, с двумя столами;
   нет пяти книг, о пяти книгах, с пятью книгами.  ГЛАВНЫМ СЛОВОМ в сочетании является СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ.

**Примечание:** Отметим, что слова **тысяча, миллион, миллиард, ноль**, которые относят к числительным по семантическому признаку,  являются грамматическими существительными и всегда **управляют Р.п. зависимого слова**

Comment: Sibilla, если не сложно, можно поподробнее о "грамматических" числительных. Такой термин существует?

Comment: Эта тема излагается в грамматике -80. Термин числительное употребляется для наименования всех слов с количественно-числовым или счетно-порядковым значением, однако с точки зрения грамматики этот класс слов не является однородным. 
   Вследствие этого возможна двоякая классификация числительных:  1) по грамматическим признакам; 2) по семантическим признакам. К грамматическим ("настоящим") числительным относятся количественные и собирательные числительные, для которых верно основное правило (управления и согласования).

Comment: Порядковые числительные являются грамматическими прилагательными, слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард - грамматическими существительными. Один - счетно-местоименное слово с признаками прил. и сущ. Дробные числительные  - это словосочетания. При классификации по семантическому принципу к числительным относятся все слова с количественно-числовым или счетно-порядковым значением, при этом они делятся на три группы: количественные, порядковые и собирательные

Comment: Спасибо, Sibilla. Собственно я всё это слышала. Давайте мы возьмём определение "грамматических" в кавычки.

Comment: Кавычки можно понять по-разному, я лучше добавлю в ответ вид числительных, к которым относится правило.